How do I use ChartJS Annotations plugin to show patterns instead of colors as a box
I understand that I can use type = label to show image in annotation as describe below
https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/samples/label/image.html
But I'm wondering if it's possible how to make images behave like the colors
Annotations on ChartJs shows on top of the plots when opaque is one
Below is the code I tried ,
image: {
   type: "label",
   drawTime: "beforeDraw",
   yMin: 22,
   yMax: 40,
   content: (context, opts) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = "https://www.onlygfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/geometric-triangle-retro-pattern-1.png";
      return img;
   },
},

It works for the whole width but it doesn't show to the yMin and yMax value.
Here's the output
UPDATE:
The idea is when I put yMin = 20 and yMax=40, it will be covered with the pattern
enter image description here
Additional photo
enter image description here

The size of the image, width and height, may be set when it is created, in pixels, and the position, in real-world coordinates is set through xValue, yValue, that correspond to the center of the label/image, see fiddle. Those values can be adapted using axes scaling, but I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, do you want to stretch the image to a certain rectangle as defined by real world coordinates xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, like in a box annotation?

Thanks @kikon, The ideal is to draw the image for each grid cell so the image doesn't look stretched. It will probably make sense to tell you the reason why it was requested. This is to mitigate issues with color blindness, Using color will be problematic for color blind people that is why the client requested for patterns instead of colors.

@kikon, I've added an update on the question since I can't paste image on the comment.

That's good, we need to make the question perfectly clear. You mentioned the grid earlier, but now if you set absolute values it's unclear how to set the height of the image, since 20 and 40 may or may not be grid lines (depending for instance on the size of the canvas if the chart is responsive)

When using the box, defining yMin and yMax automatically fill with the backcolor. I'm wondering if there's a way to make label behave the same way. I've added the wireframe the client provided on the post

For drawing the image repeatedly we're better off with a custom plugin, here's an implementation that draws the image inside each grid rectangle, if  that rectangle is between y = 20 and y = 40, jsFiddle. How is that compared to what you had in mind?

If you want to have the grid lines fixed, you can - you have to actually set the axis ticks; for a linear axis, set stepSize (docs)., e.g., stepSize: 10 for the y axis.

Just worked on what @kikon did. I hope this helps. I calculated the disctance between yAxes ticks
`https://jsfiddle.net/um2hpac6`


Thank you very much!
